# Pinterest API doesn't provide link metadata for articles

Tags: api, url, hyperlink, pinterest

I'm able to get data from the API for pins, but that data doesn't include the link of the article mentioned in the pin. I only get a link for the image URL, the link of the pin on Pinterest, and if it's a video, the video URL.
There's a section with information about the article link, except the URL! Is this an intentional omission by Pinterest? Or a bug?

In this first example, below, the pin links to this article:
http://www.bitrebels.com/geek/worlds-tallest-tunnel-slide/

```
[url] => https://www.pinterest.com/pin/601582462695976350/

[link] => https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/601582462695976350/4880694774085992885/ce2911ec61615ec208fb683a2ba0b5f956f82935841fc5971ffcfbb87413fb6f                                

[metadata] => [link] => Array
(
[locale] => en
[title] => Tallest Tunnel Slide In The World Is Not For The Faint Hearted
[site_name] => Bit Rebels
[description] => The Slide, found at ArcelorMittal Orbit in London, is the world's tallest tunnel slide and it will take you a whopping 40 seconds to reach the bottom!
[favicon] => https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/89e7e1209b5f9f9c74429abf7724bc4e3fea6b0de84bf72942765648.png?89a711f94fe87f5d1741cbaa8c2b5b94
)
```

and for a video, I get this:

```
[attribution] => Array
(
[title] => Null Stern Hotel (Landversion) â Bericht auf blick.ch
[url] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITEg_7-JVv4
[provider_icon_url] => https://s.pinimg.com/images/api/attrib/youtube@2x.png
[author_name] => sonderaufgaben2000
[provider_favicon_url] => https://s.pinimg.com/images/api/attrib/youtube.png
[author_url] => https://www.youtube.com/user/sonderaufgaben2000
[provider_name] => youtube
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The Pin object returned by the API contains a 'fillable' array, which indicates all the fields that are available.

There is an 'original_link' field which contains the link I was after, but isn't mentioned anywhere in Pinterest's API documentation.

It is the 13th/last item in the 'fillable' array, which may suggest that it was added after the API documentation was released...